# Vimeo free account capability

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo

Does anybody knows the limitation of the free Vimeo account?

I created a free Vimeo account, created an app and API key for using their API, then downloaded the player for Unity, then uploaded a video to my own Vimeo account.

When i try to play my own Vimeo video using unity, it gave a message in Unity saying i have to first be a Pro Vimeo user to play the video. The pro Account cost $240.

Am I doing something wrong, or do I actually need to be a PRO user in order to play a Vimeo video using Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Vimeo account comparison page here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/228068968-Compare-Vimeo-plans

You need a Pro account or higher to access file links for your videos hosted by Vimeo: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567

Comment: I just put the video ID into Unity, so i personally dont even see the link, their API does it, so im not sure what "access to links" really means. Also the comparison page dont really tell what the API can do for each of the payment levels.

Comment: @programmer Read here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk#streaming-requirements

"Streaming Vimeo videos requires video file access via the Vimeo API. Accessing video files is limited to Vimeo Pro and Business customers."